# Symfony 3.3 from 3.2: Compile Error: Cannot declare class Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Security\FirewallMap

Tags: php, symfony

I'm experiencing some problems since I updated from symfony 3.2 to 3.3, I got this error

```
Compile Error: Cannot declare class Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Security\FirewallMap, because the name is already in use
in classes.php (line 1709)
in ClassCollectionLoader.php (line 99)
at ClassCollectionLoader::load()in Kernel.php (line 428)
at Kernel->doLoadClassCache()in Kernel.php (line 112)
at Kernel->boot()in Kernel.php (line 168)
at Kernel->handle()in app_dev.php (line 12)
at {main}()in app_dev.php (line 0)
```

It's interesting because I only got this error accesing app_dev.php through the browser, If I directly exeucte

```
php app_dev.php
```

Then the error doesn't appear and I just get redirect to the login page as I am suppossed to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://:/login" />

        <title>Redirecting to http://:/login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="http://:/login">http://:/login</a>.
    </body>
</html>
```

Commands work fine, I can clear the cache, debout routes...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Update: here's the content of the app_dev.php

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;

/** @var \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $loader */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
Debug::enable();

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: Have you clean the cache?

Comment: absolutely, I've deleted the cache folders

Comment: can you post the contents of your `app_dev.php` file?

Comment: @lordrhodos done!

Comment: Remove you cache directory and clear the cache.                                                            1. rm -rf var/cache/dev                                                                                                          2. bin/console cache:clear

Answer (score 3):

I had what is likely very much an edge-case but maybe it will help someone.  In a Twig template I was using a constant and had at some point double-escaped the slashes in the object namespace:

`{{ constant('App\\Entity\\\\MyClass::MY_CONSTANT') }}`

which should be:

`{{ constant('App\\Entity\\MyClass::MY_CONSTANT') }}`

The extra slashes were causing this error message.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this removing vendor/symfony folder and running composer update

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Celso's answer, mine only worked if I deleted the entire vendor folder, **AND** everything in var/cache

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens to me when I actually do have the same-named classes in differently-named files.

How to reproduce it:

1. you have a file MyClass.php, with class MyClass
2. for some reason you make a copy of that file: MyClass_2.php
3. you try to clear the cache

The dreaded "Cannot declare class AppBundle\Entity\MyClass, because the name is already in use" comes again - which is actually correct, since it did see the same class name again.

In this case - just make sure you don't make any silly file backups under the web root. :)

*BTW, there's also another case when I had issues with this - when there are 2 files with same class names, in different folders, but if I remember well - this was really a Symfony bug and was handled at some point.*

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Jody's answer, the problem for me was extra escaping.

I had updated my services.yml file to use single quotes instead of double quotes.

My original version looked like this:

```
my_controller:
    class: App\Controller\MyController
    arguments:
        class: "App\\Entity\\MyClass"
```

The new version (that threw the error) looked like this:

```
my_controller:
    class: App\Controller\MyController
    arguments:
        - 'App\\Entity\\MyClass'
```

Removing the slashes (like so) is what fixed it:

```
my_controller:
    class: App\Controller\MyController
    arguments:
        - 'App\Entity\MyClass'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error after I migrated a project from symfony 3.4 to **4.4**. The error only occurred when deleting the cache.
This was due to a **require** of the same class in two different files
Replacing **require** by **require_once** solved the problem for me