# Class difinition is called twice? Cannot declare class error for symfony3.4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

When I try to load the toppage of my project.

`public/index.php`

I bumped into this error.

```
(1/1) FatalErrorException
Compile Error: Cannot declare class 
Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Admin\ContextAwareAdmin, because the name is already in use
```

I guess this means, each class's namespaces is conflicting somehow.

I have bundles in this directly and this class is declared here.

`src/Application/Sonata/ClassificationBundle`
`src/Application/Sonata/MediaBundle`

So maybe some how class definition is called twice???

and autoload setting in `composer.json`.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/",
        "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle",
        "Application\\Sonata\\ClassificationBundle\\": "src/Application/Sonata/ClassificationBundle",
        "Application\\Sonata\\MediaBundle\\": "src/Application/Sonata/MediaBundle"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/AppKernel.php",
        "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
},
```

---

I thought it is the basis of confusion,
having this kind of structre.

```
   "App\\": "src/",
        "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle",
        "Application\\Sonata\\ClassificationBundle\\": "src/Application/Sonata/ClassificationBundle",
        "Application\\Sonata\\MediaBundle\\": "src/Application/Sonata/MediaBundle"
```

So I make `psr-4` setting simple

```
  "App\\": "src/",
```

and change the namespace of AppBundle,ClassificationBundle,MediaBundle.

Every class must change the name like this, ofcourse need to change some relevant entity or classes and `use` sentences.

AppBundle -> App\AppBundle

However, after that, it works well.

Comment: Somewhere you have defined a class (e.g. `class MyClass`) more than once. Try do `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony 3.3 from 3.2: Compile Error: Cannot declare class Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Security\FirewallMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44455209/symfony-3-3-from-3-2-compile-error-cannot-declare-class-symfony-bundle-securit)

Comment: @Script47 `composer dump-autoload` return the messages `Generated autoload files containing 8 classes`

Comment: It is probably a copy/paste error.  I suspect you have a src/Application/Sonata/MediaBundle/Admin\ContextAwareAdmin.php file with a ClassificationBundle (instead of MediaBundle) namespace.